How do I convert camera's rotation from Z-Up to Y-Up?
So I have this script that exports data on the location and rotation of the camera every keyframe to a json file, and this  is working great but the problem is that I need to convert the rotation from Z-Up to Y-Up, since  the program I'll be importing the data into is a Y-Up
    camera = bpy.data.objects['Camera']

    start_frame = bpy.context.scene.frame_start
    end_frame = bpy.context.scene.frame_end

    camera_data = {}

    for frame in range(start_frame, end_frame + 1):
        bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame)

        loc, _, _ = camera.matrix_world.decompose()

        rot = camera.rotation_euler

        rot = [math.degrees(rot) for rot in rot]

        self.report({'INFO'}, "Frame: {}, Location: {}, Rotation: {}".format(frame, loc, rot))

        camera_data[frame] = {
            'location' : [loc.x, loc.z, -loc.y],
            'rotation' : rot,
            'focal_length' : camera.data.lens,
        }

    json_data = json.dumps(camera_data)

    compressed_data = (base64.b64encode(zlib.compress(json_data.encode(), 9))).decode('utf-8')

    bpy.context.window_manager.clipboard = str(compressed_data)

